# C# WPF Change Resource On Click

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, resources

My XAML is here:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <XmlDataProvider x:Key="rssSource" XPath="//item" Source="https://news.google.com/news?output=rss" />
</Window.Resources>
```

I need to change it when button click event:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <XmlDataProvider x:Key="rssSource" XPath="//item" Source="CHANGE WITH TEXTBOX VALUE" />
</Window.Resources>
```

How can i do it?

Comment: Why would you need to do this? Are you trying to switch sources for one object at some point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this maybe

```
       XmlDataProvider provider = (XmlDataProvider) this.FindResource("rssSource");
       provider.Source = new Uri("CHANGE WITH TEXTBOX VALUE");
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside the button click event put this line:

```
((XmlDataProvider)Resources["rssSource"]).Source = new Uri("<New Source>");
```